# Error creating new Team Project n Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I created a new Visual Studio Online account in order to migrate all of our projects from TFS 2010 (on=premises) to VSO. I used the OpsHub migration utility to help with this process.

During my initial testing, I created a team project on VSO and migrate it from TFS 2010 and everything's went smoothly. Then, I deleted the team project on VSO since it was only for testing.

After that, I tried to create again the same team project on VSO using the same name and I get the following error:

> The Team Project name (name of the project here) was previously used
>   and there are still TFVC workspaces referring to this name. Before you
>   use this name, the owner of each workspace should execute the Get
>   command to update their workspaces. First 1 workspaces found using
>   this name are: (name of the user here).

I don't quite understand what I should do to fix this issue. Can you please help me?

Comment: I have the exact problem in Visual Studio Online. Even if i deleted all workspaces for the specific collection, VS Online says all of the VS Online Organization members should execute *GET* command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem this morning. It looks like you have not been able to remove the old references from TFS.  The way to do this is to use the Command line on your system.

[Source](http://blog.jussipalo.com/2014/01/tfs-delete-workspace-of-another-user.html)

> You need to use TF command on Visual Studio command prompt to remove
>   the old workspace. Syntax is:
>
> tf workspace /delete (name of the project here);(name of the user here)
>
> as this was TFS Online, it was Microsoft Account, so in my case actual
>   command was
>
> tf workspace /delete "MIWORKSPACE;juss.palo@sulava.com"

Comment: I think  the correct way to use is without parenthesis: *tf workspace /delete MIWORKSPACE;juss.palo@sulava.com*